# Apache mod_rewrite on HTTP_HOST not working as expected

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've seen lots of similar questions on here but none have really helped me solve my specific issue.

I am hosting a subdomain of another server, we'll call it https://subd.domain.com, and I want all non-https requests and all requests to anything other than that URL to redirect to it. (for example, https://hostname/ and https://ipaddr/ should also redirect).

my httpd.conf file is set up like this, currently:

```
ServerName subd.domain.com
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subd\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the first case (HTTP => HTTPS) works without issue
the second case doesn't appear to be matching (in other words, no redirection occurs). I've tried commenting out the first RewriteCond to help isolate it, and various combinations of the pattern without success. I'm sure it's something minor but I'd appreciate any help.

Edit/Update #1:
For further clarification the following work (ie display the website in the browser) but redirection does not occur:

https://ipaddr/ or https://hostname/

redirection DOES work properly for all "http://" urls

I do not currently have any VirtualHosts set up in my httpd.conf, it's largely just this:

```
DocumentRoot "${WEBROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${WEBROOT}/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AuthType SSPI
    NTLMAuth On
    NTLMAuthoritative On
    NTLMOmitDomain On
    <RequireAll>
        <RequireAny>
            Require sspi-group "DOMAIN\GROUP"
        </RequireAny>
        <RequireNone>
            Require user "ANONYMOUS LOGON"
            Require user "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"
        </RequireNone>
    </RequireAll>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
    RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
    RequestHeader set X_ISRW_PROXY_AUTH_USER %{RU}e
</Directory>
```

Comment: "second case doesn't appear to be matching" - What happens exactly? By the sounds of it _nothing_?! Although if this is being processed at all I would have expected a redirect loop (at least in a default config), not "nothing". So, what is happening exactly when you request the IP address of your server? Is it reaching your site? Is the expected vHost(?) catching the request?

Comment: @MrWhite, no redirect occurs. So when I access [https://ipaddr/](https://ipaddr) or [https://hostname/](https://hostname/) in the browser, the page comes up with those urls in the address bar (but with an SSL error obviously because the domain doesn't match the cert)

Comment: @MrWhite to further answer your questions: yes, IP/hostname requests still reach the site. as for your other question, I don't have any vHosts configured, just a single Directory block:
DocumentRoot "${WEBROOT}/htdocs" followed by:
<Directory "${WEBROOT}/htdocs"> ... </Directory>